# Parameters Issue

Tags: sql, parameters

I would appreciate your support to understand what is wrong with the code below:

```
SELECT [Name] As Milestone, [Start], [Outgoing tasks] As OTask 
FROM [Sheet1$] 
WHERE [Main project] = 'Company A' AND [Main link] = 'Project 1' 
AND [Task class] = 'Company' 
AND [Start] > (SELECT [Start] 
               FROM [Sheet1$] 
               WHERE [Main project] = 'Company A' 
               AND [Main link] = 'Project 1' 
               AND [Name] = OTask 
               AND [Incoming tasks] = Milestone)
```

What I am actually trying to do is getting the registry (`Name`) which happens after its successor (`Outgoing tasks`).

Is there an issue with my parameters (Milestone and OTask)?

```
ERROR: NO VALUE GIVEN FOR ONE OR MORE REQUIRED PARAMETERS
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: What database is this? The syntax looks weird.. Also, what makes you think something is wrong? Did you get an error message? If so, post it. We can't read your mind!

Comment: What happens? Error message? Or is returned data not what you expected?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Milestone and OTask aren't SQL parameters, they're Aliases.  Are you getting an error?  What's going wrong, exactly?

Comment: @BrendanLong  I'm quite sure he's trying to query an Excel sheet using an MS ODBC gateway

Comment: You can't use `OTask` which is defined in the outer query inside the inner query!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use your alias in your where condition.

It should look like this instead

```
SELECT [Name] As Milestone, [Start], [Outgoing tasks] As OTask 
FROM [Sheet1$] 
WHERE [Main project] = 'Company A' AND [Main link] = 'Project 1' 
AND [Task class] = 'Company' 
AND [Start] > (SELECT [Start] 
               FROM [Sheet1$] 
               WHERE [Main project] = 'Company A' 
               AND [Main link] = 'Project 1' 
               AND [Name] = [Outgoing tasks]
               AND [Incoming tasks] = [Name])
```

You have to replace `OTask` by `[Outgoing tasks]` and `Milestone` by `[Name]`